# dynamic display of test without using textview : Android

Tags: android, textview

Actually I want to show some text using dynamic variable , along with want to take an another input from user so I want a input text thing & send button too.

I googled but every place i am getting that i need to use this kind of code

```
 TextView textView = new TextView(this);
 textView.setTextSize(20);
 textView.setText("score :"+test+"\n x : 3\n  y : 8");
 setContentView(textView);
```

But using this full layout becomes textview & i cant add button , if i do , i can't see them on screen .All i see is the text above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm reading this correctly, you want to have a layout which is something like this:

```
<RelativeLayout ....>
    <EditText .... />
    <Button ..... />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/scoreDisplay" ..... />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Then, in your activity's onCreate:

```
setContentView(R.layout......);

TextView tv = findViewById(R.id.scoreDisplay);
tv.setTextSize(20);
tv.setText("score :"+test+"\n x : 3\n y : 8");
```

This will have a layout containing 3 elements (an EditText, a Button, and a TextView).